# Confirm User to Change Route without saving details while editing Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, router

If the user is editing something and try to change the route without saving details.

in this condition I want to alter the user that 'your changes are not saved do you want to go away'. according to the user can we prevent component to destroy the component.

I try a guard but guard run before ngOnDestroy method run.
So what should I do?

Comment: How does the route change? On button click?

Comment: @Thiagz  Route can be changed from Navigation Bar from Header Component or from Browser's back or Forward button. I don't want to user to navigate or destroyed component if details or not saved in any form in any component

Comment: Why don't you use an onclick event to trigger the message that you need?

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular CanDeactivate for this purpose .

Link of canDeactivate Angular

https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/index/CanDeactivate-interface.html
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html

Also a working example @
https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/

AdvancedConcepts - > guards

Comment: its should can you show the code you are trying or a plunker for the same ?

Comment: `export class EditorGuard implements CanDeactivate<any> {
  constructor(private customEmitterService: CustomEmitterService) { }
  canDeactivate(component: any, currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, currentState: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (this.customEmitterService.isEditing) {
      let confirm: boolean = window.confirm('text');
      if (confirm) {
        this.customEmitterService.isEditing = false;
        return true
      } else {
        return false;
      }

    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Here is CanActivate Guard  - `export class EditorGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private customEmitterService: CustomEmitterService) { }
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (this.customEmitterService.isEditing) {
      let confirm: boolean = window.confirm('text');
      if (confirm) {
        this.customEmitterService.isEditing = false;
        return true
      } else {
        return false;
      }

    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Above two Guard That I Have created

Comment: @ErSushil if you navigate to the link  https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ and click on guards in advanced tab and click back you will find in console its printing i  am navigating away and also there is a disacrd change pop up its works fine

Answer (score 0):

i have Used CanDeactivate for the same functionality and it is working great.

Comment: Can you please explain for multiple components?

Comment: all you have to do is to add , canDeactivate: [YourDeactivateGuard] for all the routes for which you want to implement this. 

In your CanDeactivateGuard do something like this:

`@Injectable()
export class DeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<any> {
  canDeactivate(component: any) {
         //Return True or false as per condition   
    }
    return true;
  }
}`

Comment: Guard only fire once. While Navigating fro Child to parent Gaurd  doesn't fire

Comment: If you are using separate routes for each parent/child component then i will fire whenever you will try to navigate away.

Comment: Yup, but  while navigating through Browser's Back button , then Gaurd doesn't fire

Answer (score 0):

trigger `NavigationStart` of Router to do jobs before leaving current route.

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
  ..
  this.router.events.forEach((e: any) => {
    if (e instanceof NavigationStart) {
      // do confirm here.
    }
  });
}
```